# MySQL query with Inner Join returns all records in Stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures, inner-join

I have a database where I use an inner join to return a more useful set of information.  When I run:

```
SELECT `invoices`.`property`,`invoices`.`invoice_number`,`invoices`.`date`,`customers`.`company_name`,`invoices`.`total`
FROM `invoices`
INNER JOIN `customers` ON `invoices`.`customer` = `customers`.`customer_id`
WHERE `invoices`.`property` = 'CGC' ORDER BY `invoices`.`date` DESC;
```

On its own, I get back exactly what I expect.

[image]

But when I create a stored procedure with the same query, accepting a single argument, a la:

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `techrentals`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `getInvoiceList`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` PROCEDURE `getInvoiceList`(IN prop_id INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT `invoices`.`property`,`invoices`.`invoice_number`,`invoices`.`date`,`customers`.`company_name`,`invoices`.`total`
    FROM `invoices`
    INNER JOIN `customers` ON `invoices`.`customer` = `customers`.`customer_id`
    WHERE `invoices`.`property` = prop_id ORDER BY `invoices`.`date` DESC;
    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

And then I execure that stored procedure:

```
CALL getInvoiceList('CGC');
```

It returns every invoice in the set.

[image]

Any Idea why it doesn't return exactly the same set?  I'm no MySQL expert, but it seems to me that those should be functionally identical.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You declare the parameter type as int, but pass a string in the call.

Comment: Thanks.  I noticed that right after I posted the question.  That's how it always goes.  As soon as I post something on here the answer sneaks up on my and kicks me in the hindparts.

Comment: Be patient Frank-san.  There's a ten minute timer.